# Ionic Framework : Android Emulator unable to access services on host machine

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement the Ionic sample tutorial available at 
http://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/install-ionic.html

I am able to deploy sample app on Android Virtual Device. However the app isn't able to access the REST services hosted on the laptop. I am trying to access the service by changing "localhost" to "10.0.2.2". I have also added the below in the config.xml

`<access origin="*"/>`

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: any feedback on my answer? cheers.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some experiments I've done so far. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using one of the latest versions of cordova you must install the [cordova plugin whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

if you use the option `--save` it will add a section to your **config.xml** file:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save
```

You can read some useful info [here](http://devgirl.org/2015/04/24/apache-cordova-newsflash/) about important change in recent cordova updates.

You need to have this:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

set in your **config.xml** file.

If you're using the **android emulator** you have to change `localhost` in `10.0.2.2` and, of course, you have to add the port if it is different from the default: 80.

Reference [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

If you're using [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com) (**much better than the android emulator**) the ip address is going to be: `10.0.3.2` + the port num.

**Samples**

**Android emulator**: http://10.0.2.2:6050/api/checkstatus
**Genymotion**: http://10.0.3.2:6050/api/checkstatus

If you want to have debug infos for the android emulator run this from the command line:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 logcat
```

If you're running you web server in **IIS Express** chances are your request cannot reach the host.
There are a few options here. My favourite solution is to use [iisexpress-proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy).
You can install it as an npm package:

```
npm install -g iisexpress-proxy
```

and run it specifying the proxy port:

```
iisexpress-proxy 6050 to 3000
```

Now you can change your port for your emulators:

**Android emulator**: http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/checkstatus
**Genymotion**: http://10.0.3.2:3000/api/checkstatus

Probably the best solution is to use a real android device and debug your app with chrome inspect.

You have to:

- enable USB debugging on your mobile
- visit this [link](http://chrome://inspect/#devices) in chrome browser (**chrome://inspect/#devices**)

Once your device show in the list you can hit F12 and see what kind of errors your getting in the browser console.

You can even use the port forwarding forward request to an internal server; basically you can access your hosted services on your laptop through a virtual port you're going to define.

Comment: Still getting the same error "URL blocked by whitelist: http://10.0.2.2:5000/sessions"

Comment: Thanks. Followed the instruction in the link http://devgirl.org/2015/04/24/apache-cordova-newsflash/ and it resolved my issue :)