# Ionic project not working on real device using web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I am developing an mobile application for android using Ionic and Web Api.

The application working fine when I run this app on the browser emulator but when I trying to deploy on real device it gives me an error login failed.

In app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'services.hub', 'ngStorage', 'angularUUID2', 'ui.bootstrap', 'roy.signalr-hub','angularMoment'])
    .constant('/api', {
        url: 'http://ipAddress/api'
    })
```

ionic.project file

```
{
  "name": "ChatApp",
  "app_id": "",
 "proxies": [
  {
    "path": "/api",
    "proxyUrl": "http://ipAddress/api"
  }
  ]
}
```

Having an login screen click on login should be happen. I am not able to debug the code using real device also.

Comment: What type of error are you getting and what type of device?  If it's on Android, you may want to look and see if you've installed android-whitelist.  I've had that problem just recently and it fixed it for me.  But let me know what the exact error is and I'll try to help.

Comment: @Indy-Jones doing for android. I have just updated the question

Comment: @Indy-Jones also  android-whitelist is installed

Comment: @MartinP: I guess you're using IIS Express. Am I right? Best option is to install [IISExpress Proxy](https://github.com/icflorescu/iisexpress-proxy) and configure the device in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working only on Android Device, I will suspect you are working on a Windows. If that's the case, then when you run the project in your device, the console should be working. If it does not show you any error, then there's a logic error in the code. But as a suggestion, use **console.log** on cases like this one.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `console.log()` or 'ionic alert()'.