# "$http.get" does not work on IOs with IONIC

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Simple as the title suggests:

I have a development done in IONIC 1 where it correctly executes "$ http.get", works perfect for Android, but not for IOs, it simply does not throw any error just does not execute "$ http.get".

The portion of the code is:

```
$http.get("http://www.paginaquedireccionafuncionabien")
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.libroPrimero = response.records; 
    }, function(err) {
       console.error('ERR', err);
});
```

For Android works well this execution, but not for IOs, without throwing any error, it directly seems not to run.

In config.xml, among other statements, I have:

```
<Access origin = "*" />
```

Do you know how I can make IOs take the "$ http.get"?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular & Ionic, HTTP Get not working in real device IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389825/angular-ionic-http-get-not-working-in-real-device-ios)

Comment: Apply _"cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist"_ not work for me. 
This does not apply to IOS. Not duplicate so. 
**Does anyone know how to apply http for ios with ionic?**

Comment: @Alan Nexus Have you found the solution?I am trying to find this solution  since two days