# Https GET request not working on native device

Tags: ios, angular, http, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using the latest version of Ionic and I'm facing a problem when making a Https request to an external API, which requires authorization:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(`${this.username}:${this.password}`)
    })
  }

  check(upc: string) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.entrypoint + upc, {headers: this.headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res['success'] ? res['products'][0] : null);
        })
    })
  }
```

When doing this from a browser (`ionic serve`) it works seemingly, but when doing from an iPhone (using Ionic DevApp), the authorization fails, because the header is not sent.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389825/angular-ionic-http-get-not-working-in-real-device-ios?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I've already added this plugin, but still not working

Comment: are u using IOS 9 ?

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka I'm using iOS11

Comment: Not sure this is relevant but check this https://gist.github.com/mlynch/284699d676fe9ed0abfa

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka As I'm trying to make the request via HTTPS, I don't think that I'm validating any transport security rules

Comment: Anything in the Xcode logs or the web inspector console? What does the web inspector network tab show?

Comment: @jcaron I only get an 401 error, when sending the request to a self-hosted API there is no header in the request

Comment: @MichaelCool have you checked the value of `this.headers` when you call `check`?

Comment: @jcaron Yes, it is fine. There’s just something I’m not considering in Cordova or iOS