# parse.com getting status 404

Tags: android, parse-platform, ionic-framework

I am trying to use parse for ionic,
my code is doing login form with ionic.
the issue that when I am testing on chrome all is working correclt.
but when I am testing on android I am getting error, when I call

Parse.User.logIn

> code: 100 message: "XMLHttpRequest failed: {"statusText":"Not
>   Found","status":404....

my code is:

```
 login: function (user) {
            Parse.User.logIn(user.email, user.password, {
                success: function (user) {
                    // Do stuff after successful login.
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-loginConfirmed');
                },
                error: function (user, error) {
                    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('event:auth-login-failed',error);
                }
            });
```

from network:

POST https://api.parse.com/1/login 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the same old problem with the white-list.
Try to add the white-list [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

This [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288059/ionic-framework-android-emulator-unable-to-access-services-on-host-machine/30290701#30290701) might help you.

Comment: thnx a lot that was the issue!:)

Comment: Glad I've helped. An upvote would be very much appreciated :-)